# Асинхронные запросы в Java

Tags: java-ee, java, jsp, background-task

Начинаю изучать Java, перехожу с C#. Поэтому мне интересно узнать самый простой способ выполнения асинхронного запроса. Как я понимаю, следует использовать таски в обработчике запроса. Какие могут быть подводные камни в этом случае?

Не смог найти материала об этом в литературе по Java. Буду рад, если поделитесь ссылкой.

Answer (score 3):

Для выполнения асинхронных операций на сервере лучше использовать [AsyncContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html). Преимущества такого подхода подробно описаны в [этой](http://jenya-p.ru/home/1-blog/6-servlets30.html) статье (раздел "Асинхронная обработка"). Следует отметить, что AsyncContext поддерживается начиная с Java 6 и Servlet 3.0, так что убедитесь, что ваш контейнер сервлетов поддержтвает эту функциональность. Вот ещё [статья](http://ynovikov.wordpress.com/tag/asynchronous-servlet/), в ней есть пример применения AsyncContext.